# Merge two different object lists into one with a shared id field

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two different objects list like those:

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
}

public class Name {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

My `Person` list doesn't have the field **name** filled. I need to merge it with the `Name` list matching the field **id**.

**Question**: How is the best way to do this with **Java 8** streams?

Comment: Why do you want to use streams for this?

Comment: I get these two list from database (with JpaRepository). In case that the id doesn't exist we can store a empty string, and the order of the elements doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, using a `Map` is better for accessing the `Name` objects, so using streams here is a solution:

```
List<Person> personList = ...
List<Name> nameList = ...
Map<Integer,String> nameMap = nameList.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Name::getId,Name::getName));
personList.forEach(person -> person.setName(nameMap.getOrDefault(person.getId(), "")));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
 Map<Integer, String> map = names.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.id, o -> o.name));
 for (Person person : persons) {
    person.name = map.getOrDefault(person.id, "");
 }
```

Assuming names is your list of `Names` and persons is your list of `Person`, also if the person `id` is not found the default `name` is the empty string.